# How to get the physical address of the program running with gem5 emulator?

Tags: gem5

I'm running a piece of my program on gem5. I want to get the location of a data in the L2 cache, that is, its cache index.
I can get the corresponding virtual address and translated physical address in the debug log. But I would like to ask if I can get it in the program?
If it is running on a real machine, it can be obtained by directly reading /proc/self/pagemap with root authority.

But what should be done on gem5?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little bit vague. If you want to search the cache with a virtual address you can simply add modify cache.cc and add your code there. Each cache(l1d, l2c and llc) receives requests in packet objects from which you can compare against the address. Cache.h has all the fields for you to explore.